# Why do I get the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode') error only when I log in as admin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, syntax-error, typeerror

I have a js code that takes care of deleting the user account and showing a popup only when you hit the "delete user" button. In addition, I have a small function that allows you to show and hide the password if you click on the icon. Everything works fine but I notice an error in the console which is the following: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentNode'). at insertAfter referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling); at insertAfter(lastInput, Adiv);`

Why am I getting this? Am I doing something wrong ? Furthermore, the error occurs only when I log in to the site as admin, if I log in as a user it does not occur.

This is my little code

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

/* New Div */
const Adiv = document.createElement("div");
Adiv.setAttribute('class', 'input-group-delete');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#plugin_delete_me_shortcode_password");
const lastInput = inputs[inputs.length - 1]
insertAfter(lastInput, Adiv);
inputs.forEach(inp => Adiv.append(inp))

/* New Input */
var InputA = document.createElement("input");
InputA.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
InputA.setAttribute('class', 'switch');
InputA.setAttribute('id', 'field_3');
InputA.setAttribute('onclick', 'showPassword("plugin_delete_me_shortcode_password")');

var input = document.getElementById("plugin_delete_me_shortcode_password");
insertAfter(input, InputA);

/* New Label */
var newL = document.createElement("label");
newL.setAttribute('for', 'field_3');
newL.setAttribute('class', 'fa');

var input = document.getElementById("field_3");
insertAfter(input, newL);
```

Comment: Also I must say that the newInput appears only when the user is logged in. As an admin, I cannot see it because I am not allowed to delete my account.

Comment: console.log `referenceNode` in `insertAfter` function, this will help you to see whether the elements are present or not